# Manipulate JSON with python

Tags: python, json, ansible

I'm trying to manipulate JSON data to match a specific format for Ansible. I'm new to python and programming in general.  I can't quite seem to figure out how to do that.  Here's my relevent code:

```
import os
import sys
import argparse
import ConfigParser

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

import requests

payload = 'query=SELECT+TOP+10+IPAddress,+Vendor+FROM+Orion.Nodes'
url = "https://10.150.199.44:17778/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/Query"
req = requests.get(url, params=payload, verify=False, auth=('dmitry', 'security'))

jsonget = req.json()


def get_list(self):
        hostsData = jsonget
        print "Test json before manipulation:\n"
        print(hostsData)
        print "\n\n"
        for item in hostsData['results']:
            print '' + item['Vendor']
            for item in hostsData['results']:
                print 'hosts:' + item['IPAddress']
```

This is my output:

```
./swinds.py --list
Test json before manipulation:

{u'results': [{u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.190.2'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.250.3'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.255.255.42'}, {u'Vendor': u'Juniper Networks/NetScreen', u'IPAddress': u'10.58.1.1'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.1'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.2'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.3'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.4'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.6'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.7'}]}



    Cisco
hosts:10.150.190.2
hosts:10.150.250.3
hosts:10.255.255.42
hosts:10.58.1.1
hosts:10.33.93.1
hosts:10.33.93.2
hosts:10.33.93.3
hosts:10.33.93.4
hosts:10.33.93.6
hosts:10.33.93.7
Cisco
hosts:10.150.190.2
hosts:10.150.250.3
hosts:10.255.255.42
hosts:10.58.1.1
hosts:10.33.93.1
hosts:10.33.93.2
hosts:10.33.93.3
hosts:10.33.93.4
hosts:10.33.93.6
hosts:10.33.93.7
Unknown
...
```

What I'm trying to do is output something like this Ansible can read:

```
{
    "Cisco"   : {
        "hosts"   : [ "10.150.190.2", "10.150.250.3" ],
            },
    "Unknown"  : 
        "hosts"   : [ "10.255.255.42" ],
},
```

Thanks for any help.

CB

Comment: Are those real credentials for that server, and is the URL actually real?? :O

Comment: Dude...........anonymize the data before posting..........

Comment: `10.0.0.0/24` is private networks...

Comment: Is the problem related to converting one structure to another?

Comment: Dmitry, it's sample data pulled from a test version of Orion in a test env.  Also it's RFC1918 addresses.  I'm new to programming not networks/sec.  Thanks for concern though.

Comment: Celdor, yes.  I need to take the data I have and output like the last block of code.  This is how ansible reads inventory.  Where Cisco is the group, all the IPAddress values become the hosts.  So I need to somehow loop all the hosts under their corresponding group(Vendor).

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#script-conventions

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

```
import pprint
import simplejson

# Your long string
s = {u'results': [{u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.190.2'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.250.3'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.255.255.42'}, {u'Vendor': u'Juniper Networks/NetScreen', u'IPAddress': u'10.58.1.1'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.1'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.2'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.3'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.4'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.6'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.7'}]}



# Eval the Json to python friendly dict
dumped = eval(simplejson.dumps(s))

# Make a set of vendors (no duplicates)
vendor_set = set()
for value in dumped['results']:
    vendor_set.add(value['Vendor'])

# Make a new dict based on these vendors
final_dict = dict.fromkeys(vendor_set)

# Loop over the dict, conditionally adding IPAddresses to the hosts key for each vendor
for key in final_dict:
    for v in dumped['results']:
        if final_dict[key] is not None:
            if key in str(v):
                final_dict[key]['hosts'].append(v['IPAddress'])
        else:
            final_dict[key] = {'hosts': []}

# Print it (somewhat) nicely
pprint.pprint(final_dict)

# Prints:
{'Cisco': {'hosts': ['10.150.250.3',
                     '10.33.93.1',
                     '10.33.93.2',
                     '10.33.93.4',
                     '10.33.93.7']},
 'Juniper Networks/NetScreen': {'hosts': ['10.58.1.1']},
 'Unknown': {'hosts': ['10.255.255.42', '10.33.93.3', '10.33.93.6']}}
```

Comment: Gotcha.  I need all IPAddess to be under the group(Vendor key).  That's why I had the loop.  Note below the Cisco, then below in the hosts key all the IPAddress values.  This is how ansible reads data for inventory.  

{
    "Cisco"   : {
        "hosts"   : [ "10.150.190.2", "10.150.250.3" ],
            },
    "Unknown"  : 
        "hosts"   : [ "10.255.255.42" ],
},

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#script-conventions

Comment: Try this ^ @FunkyClicker .

Comment: It's close.  When I run it I get a null at the end which ansible doesn't like.

./swinds.py --list
{'Cisco': {'hosts': ['10.150.250.3',
                     '10.33.93.1',
                     '10.33.93.2',
                     '10.33.93.4',
                     '10.33.93.7']},
 'Juniper Networks/NetScreen': {'hosts': ['10.58.1.1']},
 'Unknown': {'hosts': ['10.255.255.42', '10.33.93.3', '10.33.93.6']}}
null

Comment: hmm. I cannot reproduce that problem. I don't get that result when I execute a python file with my exact code in it. This may be coming from your original long string (what I assign to 's')... Is there perhaps a null value in there?

Comment: I mean, worst case scenario, you can just get rid of that by using `pprint.pprint(eval(str(final_dict).replace('null', '')))` But I'd recommend finding where it's coming from on your side, time permitting.

Comment: No.  I changed the query for only 2 entries:

./swinds.py --list
Test json before manipulation:

{u'results': [{u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.190.2'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.250.3'}]}



{'Cisco': {'hosts': ['10.150.250.3']}}
null

Comment: I tried that, it's still there. I did notice that the first IPAddress does not print.  This should have two IP addresses, but prints only one. Maybe the value is nulled out and moved to the end?  {'Cisco': {'hosts': ['10.150.250.3']}} null